# Create relationship with wildcard but only within same node type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lets say I have 2 node types: `Node1` and `Node2`.
They both have the same property `{order:Integer}`

Now I want to create the relationship that nodes with `order:2` have an `"AFTER"` relationship with nodes with `order:1` BUT, I only want to create the relationships within the same node type.
That is, `Node1{order:2}` should have an `AFTER` relationship to `Node1{order:1}` but no relationship to `Node2{order:1}`

When I use a wildcard, it matches and creates relationships across node types which I do not want.

```
MATCH (s:%{order:2}), (f:%{order:1})
CREATE (s)-[o:AFTER]->(f)
```

How can I achieve what I want without hard-coding each edge creation explicitly?
This is what I want to avoid:

```
MATCH (s1:Node1{order:2}), (f1:Node1{order:1}), (s2:Node2{order:2}), (f2:Node2{order:1})
CREATE (s1)-[o:AFTER]->(f1), (s2)-[o:AFTER]->(f2)
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have smart wildcard (I'm using `SAMETYPE` as a placeholder), that matches same to same. Like so:

```
MATCH (s:%SAMETYPE{order:2}), (f:%SAMETYPE{order:1})
CREATE (s)-[o:AFTER]->(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each node in your database, has only one label, then this will work for you:

```
MATCH (s{order:2}), (f{order:1})
WHERE labels(s)[0] = labels(f)[0]
CREATE (s)-[o:AFTER]->(f)
```

In this query, we fetch all the nodes and check whether their label is same or not, and create the relationship accordingly.